# Problem With microphone in apps on genymotion - Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, microphone, genymotion

0

I have a problem like this, y trying send a voice comment for Whatsaap, in my virtual android on genymotion, but only send a several hit, like a "chic..chic..chic"

I trying chage my sound default in alzamixer

```
Defoult
1 HDA interl HDMI

2 HDA INTEL PCH-

on Geny I don't know, but i think, 2 most be a default? if this think is correct, i cant set 2 like default.
```

I trying change config sound in VBOX6, only i cant listen all sound from Adroid on Geny is : ALSA host driver and controller ICH AC97 , i can listen all, and the microphone recording, but with trash sound.

Someone knows how to fix this problem??

UBUNTU 18.04 Geny 3.0.1 Personal use. VBOX6

THANKS:......